# CSS3 Gradient and a Centered div Made Responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive, centering, css-gradients

How do I make this responsive? I would like the gradient and text to resize and stay centered as the screen size changes. Right now, the gradient will repeat at times and the font stays the same. I want the first section to be 100vh and the second section (no markup yet) should not have the gradient.

https://codepen.io/Shalise/pen/QOwbZJ

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
    
h1 {
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 200px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Raleway;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3em;
}
    
body {
  background: #ff7043; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */    
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #ff7043, #ffc17); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ff7043, #300032); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ff7043, #300032); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #f79f79, #f7d08a); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

```html
<section id="gradient">
  <h1>The Sun Will Come Out Tomorrow</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Using vertical width as suggested by @Aaqib fixed the font issue.

However, the gradient still repeats vertically when the window narrows.

Comment: @Uğur_Erdal, marking the h1 relative positions the text at the top of the page.

Comment: I have updated it with correct Jsfiddle , Hope now it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [vw](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) instead , so

```
html, body {
  height: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
}
```

and

```
h1 {
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 200px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Raleway;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3vw;
}
```

To Stop the gradient repeats vertically when the window narrows inside body Use:

```
body{
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Here is the UPDATED : [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Panther_007/aom7Lv0c/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: relative;` instead of `position: absolute;`

Also put on this code `font-size: 3vw;`

Answer (score 0):

```
    html, body {
      height: 100vw;
      margin: 0;
    }

    h1 {
      width: 100%;
      top: 50%;
      left: 0;
      line-height: 200px;
      margin-top: -100px;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Raleway;
      color: white;
      font-size: 2vw;
    }

    body {
        background: #ff7043; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */    
    }

    #sun {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #ff7043, #ffc17); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
      background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ff7043, #300032); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ff7043, #300032); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #f79f79, #f7d08a); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
    }

<section id="sun">
    <h1>The Sun Will Come Out Tomorrow</h1>
</section>
```